# how to add an info circle in an infoBox shiny R

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I want to add an info circle in an infoBox as an actionButton , by clicking at it we can see a definition . this is my code, I want to visualize the def of `ratio`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))

                      )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        # First tab content
                        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                                fluidRow(

                                  infoBoxOutput("ratio")
                        )
                        ))))
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ratio = renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("ratio",10*2, icon = icon("users"))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Like in this picture:

[image: like in this picture]

I only have this one:

[image: i only have this output]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: i added the picture of my output and what i wanted to add. I'm wondering if it's possible to get it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace the users icon with an info icon in the infobox? This can be done by replacing users by info in the icon() function.

```
infoBox("ratio",10*2, icon = icon("info"))
```

Shiny uses the Font Awesome library of icons, so you can find other icons on their [website](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

Answer (score 0):

well I did find a solution but I'm not really satisfied : here is the code and the image of my output (I couldn't move the info icon to the top right of my box and didn't like the form of the message) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzcUi.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))

    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(

                infoBoxOutput("ratio")
              )
      ))))
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ratio = renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("ratio",10*2, icon = icon("users"), 
            subtitle = HTML("<a id=\"button\" href=\"#\" class=\"action-button\">
     <i class=\"fa fa-info-circle\"></i>

                                                       </a>"))
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    shinyjs::info("definition")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```